# monitor SQS queue with CloudWatch

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-cloudwatch

Hope you all doing well, I am new with SQS and Cloudwatch and I need to create a Cloudwatch that would monitor SQS and would trigger Lambda with an event every time a message enters and every time a message is left.

On another note, the lambda function should scale up and down ASG service. So if anyone has a cookbook regarding those issues it would be very helpful

thank you so much!

Comment: How long does it take for an EC2 instance to process a message? Can an instance process _multiple_ messages in parallel? Have you considered processing the messages using an AWS Lambda function instead (without using an EC2 instance)?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your requirement is to **scale Amazon EC2 instances when messages are waiting to be processed in an Amazon SQS queue**.

The correct architecture for this would be to configure the Auto Scaling group to **use a scaling policy** based on the metric `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible`. This is a metric that Amazon SQS queues send to Amazon CloudWatch Metrics. There is **no need to use an AWS Lambda function**.

For reference, see:

- [Scaling based on Amazon SQS - Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html)
- [Rapid Auto Scaling with Amazon SQS | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/auto-scaling-with-sqs/)

Comment: Hi John, thank you for your answer! basically, you are saying that I can configure a scaling policy straight with ASG. does the ASG would know if the SQS receives or retrieve a message by itself and scale up and down according to this information with the metric you mentioned above?

Comment: The above metric is the number of messages waiting in the queue to be processed. You could configure it to target a particular number, or even tell it to add instances if the quantity exceeds a value (eg add more instances if it is more than 5 messages waiting). Please note that it is not instance -- the metric is calculated over a period, so it can take time before it decides to scale, and then it also takes time to add an EC2 instance.